# My Javascript Timer Speeds Up Every Time I Press the "Start" button

Tags: javascript

Every time I click the "start" button the timer speed up. And in reverse if you press the "stop" button it starts to slow down and eventually stops. Any way to stop this and just make it where when you press "start" it starts but doesn't speed up?

```
function timeKeeper() {
  var h1 = $('#headTime')[0],
    start = $('#start'),
    stop = $('#stop'),
    clear = $('#clear'),
    seconds = 0,
    minutes = 0,
    hours = 0,
    t;

  function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
      seconds = 0;
      minutes++;
      if (minutes >= 60) {
        minutes = 0;
        hours++;
      }
    }

    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) :
      "00") + "." + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) :
      "00") + "." + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
  }

  function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
  }

  /* Start button */
  $('#start').on('click', function() {
    timer();
  });

  /* Stop button */
  $('#stop').on('click', function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
  });

  /* Clear button */
  $('#clear').on('click', function() {
    h1.textContent = "00.00.00";
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    hours = 0;
  });
```

Comment: When you click on `start` it starts another timer, but doesn't remove the old timer. So the timer function runs twice every second.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the old timer when you start a new one.

```
$('#start').on('click', function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    timer();
});
```